# Buddypress - Adding Tags in Profile

Tags: tags

There exist a way to add tags like: skills, favorite books, etc. to the profile?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an *extended profile field* named **Tags**.

If you need to show this in your `members-loop.php` you could add:

```
<?php bp_member_profile_data('field=Tags') ?>
```